# How can attachment names be retrieved from a JavaMailSender exception?

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I'm using org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender (Spring Framework 4.1.6). I'm sending multiple emails by calling:

```
mailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparators);
```

where mimeMessagePreparators is a MimeMessagePreparator array. Each MimeMessagePreparator is built as follows:

```
        MimeMessagePreparator mimeMessagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException {

                MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

                // get the subscribers of the attachment and put them as the recipients
                // of this email
                mimeMessageHelper.setTo(subscribers);

                // all email have the same from, bcc, reply to, subject, and body
                String fromEmailAddress = emailTemplate.getFromEmailAddress();
                mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(fromEmailAddress);

                // note: bcc the sender so that they get the email too
                mimeMessageHelper.setBcc(fromEmailAddress);

                // this will help on auto replies and bounce messages
                // also it should help on deliverability
                mimeMessageHelper.setReplyTo(fromEmailAddress);

                String subject = emailTemplate.getSubject();
                mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);

                String emailBody = emailTemplate.getBody();
                mimeMessageHelper.setText(OPEN_EMAIL_TAGS + emailBody + CLOSE_EMAIL_TAGS, true);

                // get the physical file and add as an email attachment
                FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(directory, attachment.getName()));
                mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(attachment.getName(), file);

            }
        };
```

I need to know which emails failed (i.e. had a MailException) and eventually tell the user the names of the attachments associated with emails that failed. How can I retrieve the attachment names from the exception? So far, I have

```
try {
        mailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparators);
} catch (MailSendException mailSendException) {

        Map<Object, Exception> map = mailSendException.getFailedMessages();

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Exception> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) entry.getKey();
            // get attachment names from mimeMessage? or preferably
            // get in a more simplistic way using a helper such as MimeMessageHelper
} catch (MailException mailException) {
    // how do I get attachment names here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bunch of MimeMessage objects, see the JavaMail FAQ entries starting here:

- [How do I tell if a message has attachments?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hasattach)

Essentially, you need to iterate over the parts in the message, determine which ones represent attachments, and then access whatever metadata or headers in the part you think represent the attachment "name".

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to show how I build the MimeMessage. I'm hoping that it will lend to a more specific (simple) solution. From your reference, this does seem to work though: `Multipart multipart = (Multipart) mimeMessage.getContent();
                    int multipartCount = multipart.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < multipartCount; i++) {
                        String filename = multipart.getBodyPart(i).getFileName();
                        if (filename != null)
                            logger.info("FILENAME: " + filename);
                    }`

Comment: If you know that you're always and only constructing multipart messages of this form, that will work.  It's just not a general solution.

Comment: I will always construct the multipart message as noted in above (edited) question. I noticed mimeMessage.getContent() throws two exceptions (MessagingException and IOException). If either exception is thrown, I cannot determine the attachment name associated with a failed email. If this (getContent) is the only way to get the attachment names, that seems quite a disadvantage compared to sending emails one at a time via mailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparator) where I can always know the attachment name.

Comment: It's very unlikely that getContent will throw either of those exceptions when you're dealing with a locally constructed message.